# How to access material theme in shared component in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have two react projects Parent and Common project (contains common component like header, footer)

I have material theme defined in Parent and configured in standard way using `MuiThemeProvider`.

However, this theme object is available inside components defined in Parent, but not in share project common.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Added below more details on Oct 30, 2020

Parent Component

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import themeDefault from "./CustomTheme.js";
import { MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Dashboard from "./containers/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import { Footer, Header } from "my-common-react-project";

function App() {
  const routes = () => {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  };
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={createMuiTheme(themeDefault)}>
      <div className="App">
        <Header
          logo="some-logo"
          userEmail={"test@email"}
        />
        ... app components here..
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Shared component

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Box,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core/";

import styles from "./Header.styles";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Header = (props) => {
  const classes = styles();
  const { options, history } = props;
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const handleCloseMenu = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const goto = (url) => {
    history.push(url);
  };
  return (
    <Box component="nav" className={classes.headerBox}>
      <AppBar position="static" className={classes.headerPart}>
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolBar}>
          {localStorage && localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn") && (
            <>
              {options &&
                options.map((option) => (
                  <Typography
                    key={option.url}
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    className={classes.headerLinks}
                    onClick={() => goto(option.url)}
                  >
                    {option.name}
                  </Typography>
                ))}
            </>
          )}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
};

Header.propTypes = {
  options: PropTypes.array
};
export default Header;
```

Shared Component style

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
  headerPart: {
    background: "white",
    boxShadow: "0px 4px 15px #00000029",
    opacity: 1,
    background: `8px solid ${theme.palette.primary.main}`
    borderTop: `8px solid ${theme.palette.primary.main}`
  }
}));
```

The Parent component defined `theme.palette.primary.main` as say Red color and I expect same to be applied in Header but it is picking a different theme (default) object which has  `theme.palette.primary.main` blue.

Which results in my header to be in blue color but body in read color.

Any suggestion how to configure this theme object so that header too picks the `theme.palette.primary.main` from parent theme object.

Comment: https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer for **mui V5**

```
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles' // /!\ I fixed a typo from official doc here

function DeepChild() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return <span>{`spacing ${theme.spacing}`}</span>;
}
```

Taken from [mui documentation](https://mui.com/styles/advanced/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `useTheme` or `withTheme` to inject the theme object to any nested components inside `ThemeProvider`.

- Use `useTheme` hook in functional components
- Use `withTheme` HOC in class-based components (which can't use hook)

```js
function DeepChild() {
  const theme = useTheme<MyTheme>();

  return <span>{`spacing ${theme.spacing}`}</span>;
}

class DeepChildClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { theme } = this.props;
    return <span>{`spacing ${theme.spacing}`}</span>;
  }
}

const ThemedDeepChildClass = withTheme(DeepChildClass);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: my components are in different react project and and shared component header using default theme not the theme I set in in theme provider. so this approach didn't fix the issue

Comment: @Ashutosh you are missing the point here, shared components like `Header` or `Footer` can be in any projects they want, as long as they're wrapped inside `ThemeProvider` at the top level of the app, they can then have access to the theme data from the theme context, if you want to use default theme, just call `createMuiTheme()` without params and pass it to the `ThemeProvider` at the top.

Comment: @Ashutosh Did you wrap your *Common*  project inside any `ThemeProvider`?

Comment: @NearHuscarl and Loi.  I just added sample code and details for more clarity. Thanks in advance for the help